# How to sort an SQLite Table in Swift by Date object

Tags: swift, database, sorting, sqlite.swift

I want to be able to either set a sorting condition for my SQLite Table or sort it every time a new entry is inserted.

The [SQlite docs](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#sorting-rows) say to use `query.order(expression)`

Currently this is what I have:

```swift
class SQLiteData {
    var fileURL : URL
    var tasks : Table
    var titleDb : Expression<String>
    var descriptionDb : Expression<String>
    var dateDb : Expression<String>

    init() {
        //...  
        tasks = Table("Tasks")
        titleDb = Expression<String>("Title")
        descriptionDb = Expression<String>("Description")
        dateDb = Expression<String>("Date")
        tasks.order(dateDb)
    }
```

but the line `tasks.order(dateDb)` doesn't seem to have any effect...

I also tried it in my `uploadData` function:

```swift
    func uploadData(_ title: String, _ description: String, _ date: String) {
        do {
            let db = try Connection(fileURL.path)

            try db.run(tasks.create(ifNotExists: true) { t in
                t.column(titleDb, unique : true)
                t.column(descriptionDb)
                t.column(dateDb)
            })

            let insert = tasks.insert(titleDb <- title,  descriptionDb <- description,
                                      dateDb <- date)
            _ = tasks.order(dateDb)

            let rowid = try db.run(insert)

        }

        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

but alas have not had any success doing this either. Any ideas how would I setup the table to always be sorted by `dateDb`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.order is not an attribute of the table. It is a feature of a query. The sortedTasks query below may be what you need.

```
tasks = Table("Tasks")

 sortedTasks = Table("Tasks").order(dateDb)
```